# expecting KW_EXCHANGE near 'table' in alter exchange partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, ddl

I am dealing with a table in hive which does not have partitions and with input format as textinputformat.  This is not an external table and I create it using "Create table as select" template.

I use the alter table statement to rename the table as given below:

```
ALTER TABLE testdb.temptable RENAME TO testdb.newtable;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:32 mismatched input 'RENAME' expecting KW_EXCHANGE near 'temptable' in alter exchange partition (state=42000,code=40000)
Closing: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection
```

I see it is a bug in hive.  I use the version: 
Hive 0.12.0-cdh5.1.4

How do i go about fixing this issue. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not exactly a bug, just a side effect of Open Source when it's done by a motley crew of people all around the world with no "product owner" and no incentives to use a common programming style (or run extensive regression tests, or *<insert your complaint here>*).

Aaaaaaah, now that it's said, I feel better... Let's get to the point.

**In HiveQL the `alter` command does not use the same semantics as `create` or `select`**; specifically, you cannot use the "ALTER DATABASE.TABLE" notation. If you try, then the HQL parser just fails with a queer error message, as you can see by yourself.

That's the way it is. You must type a `use` command first, then your `alter` command with just the table name. Yes, it sucks. But that's the way it is. And I see no reason why it should improve any time soon.

---

***[Update Jun-2017]***   looks like ALTER finally supports the DB.TABLE syntax, on recent Cloudera distro (tested on CDH 5.10 with Hive 1.1.0 - but since they usually include a number of back-ports in their distro, maybe it's a feature of Hive 1.2+)

Comment: By the way, I remember an edge case in Hive V0.14 where you could not RENAME a table if it was in a database "protected" by ACLs at HDFS level. Smelled like a security issue, i.e. running the HDFS commands as `hive` system account and not as the user actually requesting the RENAME. Fixed in V 1.x

Comment: And, yes, I remember another bug in Hive V0.13 where you could not DROP a table if it was not in the currently USEd database. Fixed in V0.14

Comment: Actually there are too many bugs that wish I had never seen (subtle data corruption when running analytic functions at scale, vectorized processing crashing after an ADD COLUMN on ORC, simple "temporary macros" generating random code... whatever you can think of, they've done it)

Answer (score 2):

I have similar error message it is gone after using alternative syntax, selecting schema and reference table by the short name:

 `USE mydb;
 ALTER TABLE mytable RECOVER PARTITIONS;`